# Border Radius (rounded-xl) working fine in Android but not in IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, tailwind-css

Continue...

I am using React-Native with Tailwind CSS.

Tailwind CSS - 3.3.2
ReactNative - 0.72.5

When I check in the Android and IOS simulator, Android is working fine but in IOS its not working.

I have tried wrapping the view inside another view with "overflow-hidden rounded-xl", it didn't work

Comment: <Text className="text-center text-sm font-normal bg-gray-300 rounded-xl p-4 mx-5 items-start" onPress={onPressHandler}>
                    Continue....
                </Text >
This is the View I have tried which is not working

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind css does not work with React Native I recommend to use NativeBase or NativeWind

Comment: I am using "nativewind": "^2.0.11".